# "Is/are X + adjective"

Tags: questions, syntactic-analysis, exclamations

I provide the sentence in context:

> [A couple kisses. A friend of them sees the scene and says:]
>
> *Oh, are you cute!*

This clearly means "you're so cute, sweet" and the like. So, is this sentence a sort of question?

Or, on the contrary, is this a case when subject-verb inversion is applied, so as to give emphasis to the meaning of the sentence?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/12760/13812

Comment: You might also see http://english.stackexchange.com/q/64766/13812

Comment: @zpletan: That "related" is not actually related, since in that case it is an interrogative clause, not an exclamative clause.

Comment: @BrettReynolds, in the accepted answer, the very similar exclamation, "Boy, do I!" was put as one example of a rhetorical question. See also the other question where the answerers split into two camps on whether a similar statement was a rhetorical question or an exclamation.

Comment: Yes, but this is an error. In the original sentence, it is a question. The person simply doesn't know why they eat so much and is wondering aloud. In *boy, do I* it's an assertion, expressed exclamatively. The speaker has no doubt that they do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an exclamatory clause, not a question. Other examples:

- *did that ever go well!*
- *what a success that was!*

Comment: So, similar clauses, where the regular subject-verb order is inverted, are normally used in speech as a means of emphasis, are they? And what about the intonation pattern? Is it the like of that of a regular exclamatory clause?

Comment: It's not simply subject-verb inversion. Consider that, for *what a success that was,* the declarative clause would be *that was a success.* In other words, the subject and the verb are in the same order. The intonation is falling in both versions with *what, how,* etc and without.

Comment: Alright. Then, besides the meaning (in my example, no one would think that the friend is actually asking the couple a question) the falling intonation automatically rules out that it's a question, even a rhetorical one. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Sorry, the comment above should say, "with *what* and *how* and without." The other question words don't work the same way in exclamatives.